# MouseWheelListener and MouseMotionListener not working together

Tags: java, swing, mouselistener, mousewheel, mouse-listeners

I have two listeners, 
One is MouseWheelListener which zooms into an image if wheel is scrolled.

```
jLabel1.addMouseWheelListener(new MouseWheelListener() {
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            int notches = e.getWheelRotation();
            double temp = zoom - (notches * 0.2);
            // minimum zoom factor is 1.0
            temp = Math.max(temp, 1.0);
            if (temp != zoom) {
                zoom = temp;
                Map.resizeImage(jLabel1,zoom);
            }
        }
    });
```

When I zoom in, I need to be able to drag around the image with a drag listener, I have created my Listener and registered it to the jScrollPanel like this:

```
    HandScrollListener scrollListener = new HandScrollListener(jLabel1);
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().addMouseMotionListener(scrollListener);
    jScrollPane1.getViewport().addMouseListener(scrollListener);
```

The problem is, if I add the first listener which zooms in on my image, the second listener gets generated but does not performs its function of dragging. If I remove it and zoom in on the image with a button, then the second listener gets generated as well as performs it's drag function.

Here is the HandScrollListener, it works when the listener for zooming in is not added.

```
public class HandScrollListener extends MouseAdapter
{
Cursor defCursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR);
Cursor hndCursor = Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR);
Point pp = new Point();
public void mouseDragged(final MouseEvent e)
{

    JViewport vport = (JViewport)e.getSource();
    Point cp = e.getPoint();
    Point vp = vport.getViewPosition();
    vp.translate(pp.x-cp.x, pp.y-cp.y);
    image.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(vp, vport.getSize()));
    pp.setLocation(cp);
}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
{
    image.setCursor(hndCursor);
    pp.setLocation(e.getPoint());
}

public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
{
    image.setCursor(defCursor);
    image.repaint();
}
}
```

Comment: `the second listener does not work` - define "does not work". Do the mouse events get generated? Is the calculation of the new location wrong. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @camickr edited it now

Comment: If the event gets generated but your code does nothing, then the problem is with your code. We can't guess what your code is doing. You haven't posted an [mcve]. So we can't offer any help.

Comment: @camickr I have added the code for the events too, they work when the first listener is not added so how come there is a problem in them? Even if there is a problem in them, kindly help me find it as I've been on this for hours

Comment: `if there is a problem in them, kindly help me find it` - How? I can't just stare at the code and tell you what is wrong. To debug code you need to step through the logic and display the values of your variables to see if they are what you expect. Your code is not "complete" since I can't compile it and is not "verifiable" since I can't execute the code to see if I have the same behaviour. When you post a question always include the "MCVE". Then, `if people have time`, they will look at the code for obvious problems. Sometimes people will also attempt to debug as well.